# How to stop headphones bouncing around when walking?

Tags: headphones, travel

Sometimes when I am listening to music through in ear headphones, I need to take them out in order to listen to announcements or talk to people and it is at this point my issue arises!

I only need to have the headphones out of my ears for a short time while I walk somewhere so don't want to go through the effort of unplugging them to put them away, only to get them out again 2 minutes later. I usually have them running up underneath my jacket / jumper / shirt and just dangle them down to my chest when I'm not listening to them but I have found that when I walk then headphones bounce from side to side while I walk / run and this just leads to me holding them because it irritates me. So my question is:

> **How can I prevent my headphones from bouncing around while I am walking but not listening to them?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you wear multiple layers of shirts/coats/pullovers etc and have the cord running up between your skin and the first layer, you can always just tuck the headphones between the first layer of shirt and another layer of shirt

Answer (score 6):

Today was the day that everything changed.

I found a solution to this issue and it will never trouble me again.

I wear a jacket with a front zip and poppers to cover said zip. If I simply place the headphones along the zip (so long as it is done up) and the cover them with the popper flap, they remain both protected and out of the way with no bouncing around! Pictures to follow:

1. Step one.
   Take hold of flailing headphones.

[image]

2. Step two.
   Un-popper jacket and place headphones along zip line.

[image]

3. Step three.
   Do up the popper flap to conceal and constrain the headphones.

[image]

This method would also work if you were feeding the headphones underneath your clothes as you could just feed it straight up along this zip line and that would work just as well.

Comment: Or in this specific example, pop them in your top pocket.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution would be placing the in ear headphones over your ears.

Imagine the following picture with the grey clip being your cable joining together under your chin.

[image: bad example]

This way the two headphones also don't get tangled and you already know which is right and left. When you're ready to listen to music again, you just reach up to your ears and plug the headphones back in.

Comment: I have done this method before and it does work, but I can feel a bit of a prat have earphones near but not quite in my ears!

Comment: +1 this is becoming more and more popular, i can't walk from one room to the next in the school i teach at without seeing at least a handful of students with their earbuds tucked behind their ears